# Arduino can not communicate serial (MIDI), when the USB is unplugged

Tags: arduino, serial-port, usb, midi, arduino-uno

I wanted to test the arduino MIDI example code:
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Midi
I tried it with a 9V 500mA AC/DC adapter, and i used a MIDI-USB cable to get the MIDI messages to my software (Hauptwerk).
When the Arduino's USB cable was connected to the computer (the MIDI-USB cable was connected too) it worked fine, but when I tried with the adapter and plugged out Arduino's USB cable, the software didn't received the MIDI messages.
To the serial communication I used the TX-pin like in the tutorial.

Comment: So the only difference is that the power is 5V from USB or 9V from the adapter? Does the Arduino run at all in the second case?

Comment: `To the serial communication I used the TX-pin like in the tutorial.` - Did you use *all three wires* as shown in the tutorial? Including ground? Sounds a bit like it isn't grounded.

Comment: Yes I used all three wires. But I realized, that the problem is not the arduino's serial communication, because I connected my oscilloscope to the TX-pin, when I used the wall adaptor, and I could see arduino's serial messages in the right time. So the problem is probably with my MIDI-USB cable. This cable could not communicate even if I tried to power arduino with usb charger (so with 5V). The cable could communicate in one case, when I powered the arduino board from my computer. So it seems to be a galvanic problem. I do not want to use two usb port for one use.

Comment: I found this link: http://shiftmore.blogspot.hu/2010/01/quick-and-dirty-arduino-midi-over-usb.html. Perhaps it will solve my problem, i have the same MIDI-USB cable shown in the blog.